# How can use an Access database with wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, ms-access, wordpress-admin, wordpress-ecommerce

I have a wordpress website and I have an Access database that contains users and users files . How can I use that database with wordpress database ? Should I convert it to a mysql database and inject it in wordpress users table or create another users table or use a plugin such buddypress ? 
Thank you

Comment: define "use that database".  You need to import it one time?  Or do you need a live connection?  What solutions have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to import it , I didn’t try to import it to the wordpress users table. I don’t know if it is a good practice to do it. And I saw a plugin called buddypress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one of possible way is import your access database users into wordpress via CSV. there are several plugins that you will found on google with keywords "wordpress import users".

like this [Import users from CSV with meta](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/)